# How to control layout of custom options in Magento?

Tags: theme, custom-options

I have a product with two groups of custom options and I want one group to appear in the "product info column" and the other to appear in the "block after info column".

Currently, on the product page > design tab there is only one option for the layout which controls where all product options display. There is no way to control this individually.

Comment: @hakre OK, I figured, since there was no way to do this via the admin panel, it had to be done in code, either using layout xml or phtml.

Comment: And did you find a solution? If so you can leave an answer below. If not, you can outline what you've tried so far in the question so it's clear where you're looking.

Comment: That might be the case, but we're welcoming both sort of questions here, especially in the grey area between programming and configuration where a lot of Magento development resides.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant solution - but if you *must* use custom options and you have access / ability to modify the theme I suggest the following:

- Relocate container1 and container2 in your template - these are called via `getChildChildHtml('',true,true)` in the base theme

-or-

- Name the options via a naming convention; e.g. "Region 1 - Option 1", "Region 2 - Option 2", etc.
- In the template, parse the name of all options and store in two separate arrays to be output later.

For the second option - get a list of options from a product:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$options = $product->getOptions();
```

Parse through the options and filter by naming convention:

```
$region1 = array();
$region2 = array();
foreach($options as $option){
    if($option->getType()!='drop_down'){
       if(stripos($option,'Region 1 - ')!==false){
            $region1[] = array_pop(explode('Region 1 - ', $option));
        } elseif(stripos($option,'Region 1 - ')!==false){
            $region2[] = array_pop(explode('Region 2 - ', $option));
        }
    }
}
```

Now loop over `$region1` and `$region2`, echoing as you go.

```
foreach($region1 as $option){
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: Not so nice to do this parsing in the template. Better in a Block oder Helper class.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. @Alex